# Google Cloud Builder - downloading dependencies

Tags: google-container-registry

Following on the previous question here : [Google Cloud Builder - Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42638864/google-cloud-builder-gradle)

I have implemented the same approach and it works beautifully. Yet it downloads all the dependencies every time. There is quite a bit. Is there a way to cache the commonly used dependencies somehow? Is it done automagically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Builder does not cache built dependencies between builds. Because of isolation and security concerns, all builds are on a clean workspace. We are considering different caching strategies as feature requests.

Comment: May I know if the usage of docker 17.05 and --cache-from in the latest version Cloud Builder will help? I didn't managed to get it to work though.

- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/46
- https://medium.com/@gajus/making-docker-in-docker-builds-x2-faster-using-docker-cache-from-option-c01febd8ef84